# No such property: stopPort for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.Default Project_Decorated

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gradle

When I am trying to run `'grale appenginerun'` command in my eclipse but its showing following error:

```
'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\GeekLabs\git\the-nizamabad-gradle\thenizamabad>gradle appenginerun

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\GeekLabs\git\the-nizamabad-gradle\thenizamabad\build.gradle
' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'thenizamabad'.
> No such property: stopPort for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultP
roject_Decorated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.273 secs
```

This is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'appengine'
apply plugin:'war'


sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'thenizamabad', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
appengine {
    httpPort = 8999
    downloadSdk = true
    httpAddress = '0.0.0.0'
    stopPort = 8099
    stopKey = 'STOP'
    jvmFlags = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9988',
    '-Ddatastore.backing_store=C:/gae/local_db_w.bin']

    appcfg {
        email = 'geeklabsapps@gmail.com'
        oauth2 = true
        logs {
            severity = 1
            outputFile = file('mylogs.txt')
        }
        app {
            id = 'thenizamabad'
        }
    }
        enhancerVersion = "v1"
        enhancerApi = "jpa"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
// https://github.com/mgoellnitz/tangram-examples/blob/master/example-jpa-gae/build.gradle
maven {
url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgoellnitz/artifacts/master" }
}

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.9'
        // for Enhancer
        classpath 'tangram:gradle-plugin:0.9-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    // GAE
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.9'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.9'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.9'
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

If I comments these two lines working fine:

```
stopPort = 8099
stopKey = 'STOP'
```

I don't know the reason why its happening like this?
Its working fine in my friends system but not in mine..I am using 32 bit operating system and Grdle Version: 2.2.1..

Please provide proper answer if you understood it..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this properties are defined for [jetty](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html) plugin, which isn't applied to the script.

There're no such properties defined for [appengine](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin) plugin.